# unable to get last value of JSON array in PHP

Tags: php, json

[here](https://api.blockchain.info/charts/avg-block-size?format=json) is the JSON file in question. I need to get the last `y` value from the `values` array. This updates once a day so the code below is what I've tried, but won't update to the latest value:

```
<?php
$url = 'https://api.blockchain.info/charts/avg-block-size?format=json';
$data = file_get_contents($url);
$stats = json_decode($data, true);

$blocksize = $stats['values']['363']['y'];

echo $blocksize;
?>
```

thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using:

```
$lastValue = end($stats['values']);
$blocksize = $lastValue['y'];
```

Comment: This could be improved by checking whether the `$stats['values']` exists or not first.

Answer (score 1):

You can count the array size and -1 from it

```
$blocksize = $stats['values'][count($stats['values']) - 1]['y'];
```

Comment: I was using the "count" completely wrong just now then refreshed the page. thanks!